# why am i getting this never ending loop while trying to print elements in singly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm new to data structures and I was able to implement this singly linked list in c and it worked fine. While I was trying to implement the same in C++ I was pretty much done with it except the `printList()` part. This same function worked without any issues in C but when it was executed in C++ it is going into a never ending loop. Could someone please help me on how to fix this issue.

Also, could you please suggest me some good data structure tutorials, as it was never taught in our college I can't really understand it well without spending ours watching different tutorials on YouTube for one concept.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};


Node *head = new Node;


void printList(){
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}




void insertNode(int x){
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;

    head = temp;
}

int main(){
    int n,i,x;
    cout << "How many numbers?" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "Enter data: " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        insertNode(x);
    }

    printList();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you allocate a node here instead of initializing head to null `Node *head = new Node;` BTW `head->next` or `head->data` here is not initialized. Adding this will cause Undefined Behavior. You could partially fix by adding a constructor for Node but what data would you add to signify the end of the list?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - there is nothing suspicious about that (in isolation) - all it does is ensure the newly created node is placed first in the list, and that `head` points at it.   The problem, as drescherjm noted, is that the first created node is uninitialised (when iterating over a list to print it, the nodes data will be printed in reverse order of creation, and eventually the first created node will be reached - at which point accessing its uninitialised members gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: try to lookup "smart pointers", manually managing the dynamic memory in C++ is so 2003'ish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
Node *head = new Node;
```

one reason this is a bug is you are creating a head node with uninitialized data and uninitialized next pointer. You could fix that by adding a constructor for your Node class or using

```
Node *head = new Node{};
```

or add a constructor  for Node() if you have an old compiler.

but why do you want this extra node in the list in the first place? When you go to print you will print it unless you modify your print code to ignore the last node.

The better solution would be to replace this line with:

```
Node *head = nullptr;
```

or since you are using NULL instead of nullptr

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

Comment: There's no logic to newbies writing `Node *head = new Node;` where it's not needed. It's just that they see this done a lot, and so think that somehow it's the right thing to do. They don't realise that `Node* head = nullptr;` or `Node* ptr = head;` is possible.  Sometimes you even see the memory leak `Node *ptr = new Node; ptr = head;` when the newbie wants to assign `head` to `ptr`, but thinks the `new Node` construction is somehow compulsory when dealing with pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `Node *head = nullptr` fixed the issue and I did understand why it was going into a never ending loop. :)